# SwiftUI: Opening a modal sheet with dynamic content fails only on first attempt

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

The goal is to pass dynamic content into a single modal, as if it was a detailed view:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Item {
  let number: String
  let id = UUID()
}

class ItemSet: ObservableObject {
  @Published var collection: [Item]
  
  init() {
    self.collection = []
    for index in 1...100 {
      self.collection.append(Item(number: "\(index)"))
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var items: ItemSet
  @State private var selectedItem: Item?
  @State private var showingFull = false
  
  init() {
    self.items = ItemSet()
    self.selectedItem = nil
  }
    
  var columns = [
    GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 150), spacing: 5.0)
  ]
  
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
      LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
        ForEach(items.collection, id: \.id) {item in
          Text(item.number)
            .frame(height: 100)
            .onTapGesture {
              self.selectedItem = item
              self.showingFull = true
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingFull) {
              if let item = selectedItem {
                Text(item.number)
              }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

For some reason, the first time you tap a cell, the modal is empty, as if the state was not updated before rendering the modal content, but any time after that works as intended. Am I missing something obvious or should I file a radar?

Comment: The only working solution for me was to move `selectedItem` from a `@State` in the view to a `@Published` in the model, and to move the `.sheet` out of the `ForEach`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: show different sheet items conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65567379/swiftui-show-different-sheet-items-conditionally)

Comment: @loremipsum This answers the question in a much better way than most answers here! I didn't know about sheet(item:content:), it's definitely the right way to present conditional modal content. 

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution I found is moving the sheet and state to be their own structs:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var items: ItemSet
  
  init() {
    self.items = ItemSet()
  }
    
  var columns = [
    GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 150), spacing: 5.0)
  ]
  
  var body: some View {
     ScrollView {
       LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
         ForEach(items.collection, id: \.id) {item in
          TextItem(item: item)
         }
       }
     }
   }
}

struct TextItem: View {
  let item: Item
  @State private var showingFull = false

  var body: some View {
    Text(item.number)
      .frame(height: 100)
      .onTapGesture {
        self.showingFull = true
      }
      .sheet(isPresented: $showingFull) {
        Text(item.number)
      }
  }
}
```

I don't know how "correct" this solution is in terms of being proper SwiftUI, but I haven't noticed any performance issues when used inside a more complex and heavy layout.

Comment: This helped indeed.

Answer (score 3):

This is multi-sheets conflict as you attached same sheet to every cell in `ForEach` with binding to single state, so on click they are all activated at once. The solution is to move sheet out of `ForEach`

Here is a corrected part. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

```
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
      LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
        ForEach(items.collection, id: \.id) {item in
          Text(item.number)
            .frame(height: 100)
            .onTapGesture {
              self.selectedItem = item
              self.showingFull = true
            }
        }
      }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showingFull) {      // << here !!
      if let item = selectedItem {
        Text(item.number)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ahh, yes that was a pretty silly mistake putting the sheet inside the ForEach. However, I just tried your exact body code and I get the same results: nothing inside the first modal, then everything after that works. I'm on Xcode beta 5, so perhaps this is just a regression. I'll file a radar now...

Comment: Try on simulator or real device, preview might fail.

Comment: Tried on a physical iPhone11,6, in the dynamic SwiftUI previews, and on a simulated iPhone 11; all produced the same, described result.

Comment: Same results on beta 6; feedback filed as FB8531587

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: Noticed the same issue. Did somebody report this?

Comment: This did not fix the issue for me either. Any solution?

Comment: @vikzilla, @Noim, @Urkman, probably you meet into another issue that can be solved by using `.sheet(item:` modifier, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63217450/12299030.

Answer (score 1):

encountered this same problem and solved it by switching to `sheet(item)` and removing the boolean check to show sheet

```
struct TextItem: View {
  @State let item: Item

  var body: some View {
    Text(item.number)
      .frame(height: 100)
      .onTapGesture {
        self.showingFull = true
      }
      .sheet($item) {
        Text($0.number)
      }
  }
}
```