# SwiftUI: show different sheet items conditionally

Tags: swiftui

I am failing miserably trying to wrap my head around how to use `.sheet(item:content:)`. I know that there is a lot of information here and on other platforms, but I just cannot get it to work...

Here's an abstraction of the view I'd like to have – and I don't know what I am doing wrong here:

```swift
import SwiftUI

enum SheetView: String, Identifiable {
    var id: Self { self }
    case sheetA = "Sheet A"
    case sheetB = "Sheet B"
}

struct SheetViewTest: View {
    @State private var showSheet: SheetView? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Button(action: {
                showSheet = .sheetA
                print("Button \(showSheet?.rawValue) tapped…")
            }, label: {
                Text(SheetView.sheetA.rawValue)
            })
            Button(action: {
                showSheet = .sheetB
                print("Button \(showSheet?.rawValue) tapped…")
            }, label: {
                Text(SheetView.sheetB.rawValue)
            })
        }
        .sheet(item: $showSheet) { sheet -> View in
            Text(sheet.rawValue)
        }
    }
}

struct SheetViewTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SheetViewTest()
    }
}
```

The error I am on the body getting is as follows:
`Value of protocol type 'View' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols`, which is due to the `.sheet` modifier cause when I comment it out, the view works just fine...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove closure return type (which is inferred automatically from returned content), i.e.

```
    .sheet(item: $showSheet) { sheet in      // << here !!
        Text(sheet.rawValue)
    }
```

Comment: Are you kidding me - that's why I wasted several hours this afternoon? I mean I know technically this is my fault / lack of understanding, but on the other hand code completion etc. suggested the code above... Anyway, excellent help as always!