# How to add if else statement to a button and .sheet?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI and trying to create a simple app that produces a random button each time the app starts. The random button generates a new view linked to that random button. Currently it is linked to one view which is presented each time the button is pressed.
This is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var armview: Bool = false
let workouts = ["Arms", "Legs", "Back", "Core"]

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        VStack {
            Text("Random workout for the day:")
                .bold()
                .font(.title)
        }
        Button(workoutGen()) {
            self.armview = true
        }
        .font(.title2)
        .sheet(isPresented: $armview, content: {
            ArmExerciseView()
        })
    }
}

func workoutGen() -> String {
    let workout = workouts.randomElement()
    return workout ?? "nil"
}}
```

I'm trying to find out how I can attach an if-else condition or a switch case so that I can present different views depending on which button appears and gets tapped.
So a different view for Legs, Back, Core, etc.

Comment: Use multiple SwiftUI Sheets with Switch Case. Implement OnTap conditionally to show the sheets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: show different sheet items conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65567379/swiftui-show-different-sheet-items-conditionally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var armview: Bool = false
    let workouts = ["Arms", "Legs", "Back", "Core"]
    @State private var workoutSelection = "workout selection"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Random workout for the day:").bold().font(.title)
            }
            Button(workoutSelection) {
                armview = true
            }
            .font(.title2)
            .sheet(isPresented: $armview, onDismiss: {workoutGen()}) {
                switch workoutSelection {
                case "Arms": Text("Arms") // ArmExerciseView()
                case "Legs": Text("Legs")
                case "Back": Text("Back")
                case "Core": Text("Core")
                default:
                    Text("no selection")
                }
            }
        }.onAppear {
            workoutGen()
        }
    }
    
    func workoutGen() {
        workoutSelection = workouts.randomElement() ?? "workout selection"
    }
    
}
```