# SwiftUi @State variable of type enum is nil

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

i have Four Views :

```
LoginView()
SignInWithEmailView()
SignUpView()
ForgotPasswordView()
```

the **LoginView**:

```
struct LoginView: View {
    
    enum Action {
        case signUp, resetPW
    }

    @State private var showSheet = false
    @State private var action: Action?

    init() {
        print(self.action) //prints nil
    }
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SignInWithEmailView(showSheet: $showSheet, action: $action)
            SignInWithAppleView()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
            Spacer()
        }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                if self.action == .signUp {
                    SignUpView()
                } else {
                    ForgotPasswordView()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

the **SignInWithEmailView** :

```
struct SignInWithEmailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userInfo: UserInfo
    @State var user: UserViewModel = UserViewModel()
    @Binding var showSheet: Bool
    @Binding var action: LoginView.Action?
    
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @State private var authError: EmailAuthError?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomTextField(secureInput: false, titleKey: "Email Address",
                      fieldText: self.$user.email)
                .autocapitalization(.none)
                .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
            CustomTextField(secureInput: true, titleKey: "Password", fieldText: $user.password)
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    self.showSheet = true
                    self.action = .resetPW
                }) {
                    Text("Forgot Password")
                }
            }.padding(.bottom)
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                FormButton(buttonText: "Login", buttonAction: {
                    FBAuth.authenticate(withEmail: self.user.email,
                                        password: self.user.password) { (result) in
                        switch result {
                        case .failure(let error):
                            self.authError = error
                            self.showAlert = true
                        case .success( _):
                            print("Signed in")
                        }
                    }
                })
                    .opacity(user.isLogInComplete ? 1 : 0.5)
                    .disabled(!user.isLogInComplete)
                
                FormButton(buttonText: "Sign UP", buttonAction: {
                    self.showSheet = true
                    self.action = .signUp
                })
            }
            .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
                Alert(title: Text("Login Error"), message: Text(self.authError?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")) {
                    if self.authError == .incorrectPassword {
                        self.user.password = ""
                    }else {
                        self.user.email = ""
                        self.user.password = ""
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, 100)
        .frame(width: 300)
        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        
    }
}
```

the **SignUpView** :

```
struct SignUpView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userInfo: UserInfo
    @State var user: UserViewModel = UserViewModel()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    
    @State private var showError = false
    @State private var errorString = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Group {
                    AvatarSelection()
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        CustomTextField(secureInput: false, titleKey: "Full Name", fieldText: self.$user.fullname)
                        if !user.validNameText.isEmpty {
                            Text(user.validNameText).font(.caption).foregroundColor(.red)
                        }

                    }
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        CustomTextField(secureInput: false, titleKey: "Email Address", fieldText: self.$user.email).autocapitalization(.none).keyboardType(.emailAddress)
                        if !user.validEmailAddressText.isEmpty {
                            Text(user.validEmailAddressText).font(.caption).foregroundColor(.red)
                        }
                    }
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        CustomTextField(secureInput: true, titleKey: "Password", fieldText: self.$user.password)
                        if !user.validPasswordText.isEmpty {
                            Text(user.validPasswordText).font(.caption).foregroundColor(.red)
                        }
                    }
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        CustomTextField(secureInput: true, titleKey: "Confirm Password", fieldText: self.$user.confirmPassword)
                        if !user.passwordsMatch(_confirmPW: user.confirmPassword) {
                            Text(user.validConfirmPasswordText).font(.caption).foregroundColor(.red)
                        }
                    }
                }.frame(width: 300)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                VStack(spacing: 20 ) {
                    FormButton(buttonText: "Sign Up", buttonAction: {
                        // Signup
                        FBAuth.createUser(withEmail: self.user.email,
                                          name: self.user.fullname,
                                          password: self.user.password) { (result) in
                            switch result {
                            case .failure(let error):
                                self.errorString = error.localizedDescription
                                self.showError = true
                            case .success( _):
                                print("Account Creation Successful")
                            }
                        }
                        
                    })
                    .opacity(user.isSignInComplete ? 1 : 0.5)
                    .disabled(!user.isSignInComplete)
                    
                    Spacer()
                }.padding()
            }.padding(.top)
                .alert(isPresented: $showError) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Error Creating an Account"), message: Text(self.errorString), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Sign Up", displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Dismiss") {
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                })
        }
    }
}
```

the **ForgotPasswordView** :

```
struct ForgotPasswordView: View {
    @State var user: UserViewModel = UserViewModel()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @State private var errString: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TextField("Enter email address", text: $user.email).autocapitalization(.none).keyboardType(.emailAddress)
                FormButton(buttonText: "Submit", buttonAction: {
                    FBAuth.resetPassword(email: self.user.email) { (result) in
                        switch result {
                        case .failure(let error):
                            self.errString = error.localizedDescription
                        case .success( _):
                            break
                        }
                        self.showAlert = true
                    }
                })
                
                .disabled(!user.isEmailValid(_email: user.email))
                Spacer()
            }.padding(.top)
                .frame(width: 300)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle("Request a password reset", displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Dismiss") {
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                })
                .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Password Reset"), message: Text(self.errString ?? "Success, Password reset email was sent, Check your email"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")) {
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    })
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**the problem**:

in the loginView, the first time i tap on signup button, the sheet opens ForgotPasswordView() // which is wrong

when i close the sheet and tap on ForgotPassword, the sheet open ForgotPassword // which is right

when i close the sheet and tap on signup button again, the sheet opens SignUpView // which is right

**How can i open SignupView from the first attempt ?**

Comment: Optional instances property are by default initialised with nil. If you want other value you have to do it yourself. You also do not show those views are arranged inside you main view

Comment: Based on your other comment I think you need `sheet(item)` instead of your current setup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: show different sheet items conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65567379/swiftui-show-different-sheet-items-conditionally)

Comment: Initialize your action by any .none property at first... This will fix.

Comment: i know its default initialized with nil, shouldn't it get assigned with the value i choose from the buttons as its wrapped with @State wrapper ? why doesn't it get assigned with the value i want from the binded variable coming from SignInWithEmailView ?

Comment: @Kudos unfortunately it doesn't change anything, and when i print the value out with init() {print(self.action)}, it prints nil,,because its still default initialised with nil, the problem here why it gets the appropriate value from second attempt after choosing "forgot password" then getting back to sigup button, and not from the first attempt i choose to signup ?!

Comment: @mohamedmostapha first put `enum Action {
        case signUp, resetPW
    }` out of LoginView ... and In `SignInWithEmailView`, Set `@Binding var action: LoginView.Action?` to `@Binding var action: Action?` and try

Comment: @Kudos the purpose of your solution is to move the Action enum from the LoginView to the SignInWithEmailView and there set  `@Binding var action: LoginView.Action?` to `@Binding var action: Action?`...i tried this but nothing has changed...i still get the same result :( .. looks like the first time the sheet gets opened, the value in enum Action persists to be nil, then in the 2nd attempt when i tap on "Forgot password"...the enum gets assigned with a different value...so it toggles appropriately after that...hope we can make it work appropriately from first attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this mystery , in the **LoginView** :

i changed this:

`SignInWithEmailView(showSheet: $showSheet, action: $action)`

to this:

`SignInWithEmailView(showSheet: $showSheet, action: self.action == nil ? $action : $action)`

and it works like a charm ;)

Answer (score 0):

Found this on apple dev forum.

Swift UI on iOS 14 not assigning new object to @State property - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652080

Also contains legit workaround for this Apple's bug:

make your Action to confirm some raw value, for example String and then add this in your view:

```
Text("\(action?.rawValue ?? "")"
    .hidden()
```