# Pass data in sheet and fullScreenCover, SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, view, swiftui, segue

At the moment I have a ForEach loop like this:

```
ForEach(viewModel.data, id: \.self) { data in
    Button(action: {

        self.isPresented.toggle()

    }, label: {
        
        HomepageRow(data: data)

    })
    .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
        DetailView(data: data)
    }
}
```

And i need to pass data to my DetailView which has a `var data: MyStruct` this works fine, the problem is that when I tap back and I open another detailview, the new data is not passed. I know sheet doesnt trigger .onAppear of the mainView, so my question is, how do I pass different data based on the ForEach element tapped?

---

I can observe the same behavior with the new iOS 14.0 fullScreenCover.

This is the struct:

```
 }).fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
        print("DISMISSED")
 } content: {
      DetailView(data: data)
 }
```

So what is the best approach to pass new data once the sheet or fullScreenCover are dismissed?

Comment: @Asperi, can you check if you can close this as a duplicate? I believe one of your recent posts answers this question but I can't find it.

Comment: This might help you: [iOS14 introducing errors with @State bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63928736/ios14-introducing-errors-with-state-bindings)

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63217450/12299030?

Comment: Thanks a lot both!! I forgot about the sheet signature with item. THANKS @Asperi