# Button in For Each List

Tags: list, button, swiftui, foreach

I am trying to pass information to a sheet from a button on a list. My example code always passes the "Init" string the first row you press, and after that, it shows the correct row information passed. I'm not sure why it is not correctly saving my var on the first click. Any suggestions on how to do this?

```
struct test_nav: View {
@State var ispresented = false
@State var rowText = "Init"

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List{
            ForEach(0..<10) { row in
                HStack {
                    Text("row \(row)")
                    Button( action: {
                        rowText = ("row \(row)")
                        ispresented.toggle()
                    }){
                        Text("Show Sheet")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $ispresented) {
        Text(rowText)
    }
}}
```

Comment: Use `sheet(item:` like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63217450/12299030.

Comment: Yes! I didn't even know that was possible. Perfect solution!!